# Maintaing Images when switching servers

Tags: drupal, transfer

I just changed the server one of my sites is hosted on. In doing so, I lost all the images. The CCK file upload fields show "ghost" data but contain no actual image data as they did before the site transfer.
All my data is fine, however.

Is there a way to prevent this so all my images are maintained?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer files with rsync directly or use drush to rsync. You'll need to have ssh access to the servers to get this to work.

Here's some info on setting up your drush aliases:

http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/dustin-currie/synchronize-one-drupal-site-to-another

http://drupal.org/project/drush

If you're performing this task once you could also use scp to copy files from the destination:

http://www.go2linux.org/scp-linux-command-line-copy-files-over-ssh

If you're on a shared hosting platform, just FTP the files over old school style.